# Windows Phone Periodic Task Restriction

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-agents

### Restriction of Periodic Task for Windows Phone 8

I am trying to make the app which it is using to check webservice value in the background based on the interval timer that set by user. I know the restriction of periodic task is minimal 30 minutes will run the background agent. It is giving a big problem to my app. May I ask have another way to let me check the webserivce value in interval timer instead of using periodic task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no another way to perform a web-request in background. But an app can be configured to run under a lock screen. Also using Push Notifications can be considered.

Comment: if run under a lock screen, foreground cannot be close??

Comment: Yes, you app won't go to `Dormant` or `Tombstone` and can perform web-requests for example. Check here how to implement it  http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Run_Windows_Phone_application_under_lock_screen. And another case how you can perform an update on client side is to use `Push Notifications`.